# Ran the function during project execution using rocketry

Tags: python-3.10, pyrogram

I have a code similar to this, and I want the function "do_something" to be executed when I run the project. Its job is to prepare the database, etc.

I don't know how do it. I would it if you could guide me. I have read the rocketry documentation, but I couldn't find what I need.

```py
from pyrogram import Client
from rocketry import Rocketry
import asyncio

api = Client("api")
cli = Client("cli")
rocktry = Rocketry()

async def do_something():
    await api.send_message(123456, "loading ....")
    # code
    await api.send_message(123456, "bot is ready!")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(api.start(), cli.start(), rocketry.serve())

api.run(main())
```

The idea that came to my mind is to set the value of a variable to false and then check in my code if the variable's value is false, perform this action, and afterwards set the value of that variable to true.

Answer (score 1):

```py
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(api.start(), cli.start(), rocktry.serve())
    await do_something()

api.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This will run the `do_something()` function after the clients have started and the Rocketry server has started.

Comment: This code does not work correctly because there is an await keyword on the previous line, and the next line will not be executed until that operation is completed.

Comment: @sobhani ooh.. yes you are correct .... i have edited my answer accordingly ... sorry for the confusion

Comment: thank you for your help. not worked again. I write my answer for this question

Comment: your answer not working for me :/

Answer (score 1):

I change my code to this , and it's worked correctly:

```
from pyrogram import Client
from rocketry import Rocketry
import asyncio

api = Client("api")
cli = Client("cli")
rocktry = Rocketry()

async def do_something():
    while not api_app.is_connected:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    await api.send_message(123456, "loading ....")
    # code
    await api.send_message(123456, "bot is ready!")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        api_app.start(),
        do_something(),
        cli_app.start(),
        skd_app.serve()
    )

api.run(main())
```

I don't know if it has good performance or not, but it's exactly what I was looking for.